# Error while trying to copy Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having the error "Copy Method of Worksheeet class failed" on this line:

```
.Sheets("Blank Forecast Sheet").Copy After:=.Sheets("Button Sheet")
```

I've looked around and couldn't find any solution. This code is ,as can be seen, supposed to add new sheets that I will rename, once, I get this problem solved.

```
Sub addnewsheet()

Dim wbook As Workbook
Set wbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Dim datasheet As Worksheet

Dim m As String
Dim y As Integer

m = Format(Date, "mmmm")
y = Format(Date, "yyyy")

With wbook
.Sheets("Blank Forecast Sheet").Copy After:=.Sheets("Button Sheet")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you verified your sheet names?  Your code works for me.

Comment: @BrianMStafford what do you mean by verified? I did check if I had any misspellings, extra spaces, or any other errors in the names of the sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `wbook` and `.Worksheets` instead of `.Sheets`:

```
Sub addnewsheet()

Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Dim datasheet As Worksheet

Dim m As String
Dim y As Integer

m = Format(Date, "mmmm")
y = Format(Date, "yyyy")

With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets("Blank Forecast Sheet").Copy After:=.Worksheets("Button Sheet")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please could you state the solution or rather the origine of your problem in a closing statement ? As far as we know your code, despite some imperfections, was working all along.

Comment: Glad to help. Which of the two was it exactly? And may you mark the question as answered so other people can see that there is a solution :)

Comment: Changing the names to `ThisWorkbook` and `.Worksheet`, both helped, though I did not check which specifically worked. Thank You